# Showing Nested JSON Data in Separate Rows - Angular4

Tags: arrays, json, angular, typescript, html-table

I want to show this data in separate rows cause at the moment they are getting all in 1 row only. I want to show the 'FROM' from the JSON Data

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="from">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> From </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
        <tr>{{element.computationrates[0].ratebands[0].from}}</tr>
        <tr>{{element.computationrates[0].ratebands[1].from}}</tr>
        <tr>{{element.computationrates[0].ratebands[2].from}}</tr>
        <tr>{{element.computationrates[0].ratebands[3].from}}</tr>
      </mat-cell>
  </ng-container>
```

Can someone show me how to edit this code to make them appear in different rows

**JSON Data**

```
        [
     {
  "yearlyincentive": {
      "incentive": {
          "number": "0",
          "description": "null"
      },
      "year": "2016"
  },
  "computationrates": {
          "0": {
              "computation": "0",
              "ratetype": "0",
              "ratebands": [
                  {
                      "from": "0",
                      "to": "8,000",
                      "percent": "15%",
                      "subtract": "100" 
                  },
                  {
                      "from": "8,000",
                      "to": "15,000",
                      "percent": "20%",
                      "subtract": "250" 
                  },
                  {
                      "from": "15,000",
                      "to": "25,000",
                      "percent": "25%",
                      "subtract": "500" 
                  },
                  {
                      "from": "25,000",
                      "to": "50,000",
                      "percent": "35%",
                      "subtract": "1000" 
                  }
              ]
          }
  }
 }
 ]
```

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rhX4n.png)

Comment: Not really sure what you want to archieve. Do you iterate over elements, or over ratebands? Your template is quite confusing.

Comment: Cause currently all the 'from' records under ratebands are showing all in one row.. and i want each record to be in an individual row.

Comment: But what do you want to display in the table? a) Several "elements", and each element has one row, where in one column all ratebands.from are displayed, or b) a table of one element, with all its rateband.from values in several rows?

Comment: I want to show the different rateband.from values in several rows

Answer (score 0):

When you want to iterate through the ratebands, this should be your columnDef:

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="from">
  <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> From </th>
  <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let rateband">{{rateband.from}}</td>
</ng-container>
```

Ok now I got your problem, I think. Your dataSource2 is an array of only one object, with attributes `yearlyincentive` and `computationrates`. To show the ratebands in distinct rows, you will need to give these to the table as dataSource. So either edit your .ts file:

```
// previous: 
dataSource2 = new MatTableDataSource(ELEMENT_DATA_DETAILS);
// now:
dataSource2 = new MatTableDataSource(ELEMENT_DATA_DETAILS.computationrates["0"].ratebands);
```

or edit your html:

```
<!-- previous: -->
<mat-table #table [dataSource]="dataSource2" matSort>
<!-- now: -->
<mat-table #table [dataSource]="dataSource2.computationrates['0'].ratebands" matSort>
```

Then use the columnDef at the top of my answer.

Comment: Nothing is shown when i do that code.. and no errors

Comment: Please provide a short stackblitz.com project to show how your whole MatTable looks like.

Comment: There are some errors beacuse i removed some code of the previous tables

Comment: I have an error .. i added an image in the final part of the question

Comment: Try the index-key notation, like `ELEMENT_DATA_DETAILS['computationrates']['0']['ratebands']`

Comment: Still didn't work.. Cannot read property '0' of undefined is the Error

Comment: Seems that `ELEMENT_DATA_DETAILS` is not defined at all. Are you compiling with AoT? If so, you will not be able to access a `const` defined outside of the class. Please pull the `ELEMENT_DATA_DETAILS` as member attribute into the component class and try again. Also debug with debugger or `console.log` to find out the content of `ELEMENT_DATA_DETAILS` at runtime.